# Activity and activitygroup and Tabactivity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity, activitygroup

What is the difference between activity, activitygroup and Tabactivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html): An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View). While activities are often presented to the user as full-screen windows, they can also be used in other ways: as floating windows (via a theme with windowIsFloating set) or embedded inside of another activity (using ActivityGroup).

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html): A screen that contains and runs multiple embedded activities.

[TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html): An activity that contains and runs multiple embedded activities or views.

The TabActivities will have a [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) associated with them.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out the docs.

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> An activity is a single, focused thing
>   that the user can do.

[ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) extends `Activity`:

> A screen that contains and runs
>   multiple embedded activities.

[TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) extends `ActivityGroup` to provide infrastructure for working with a `TabWidget`, or a row of tabs that allow switching between hosted activities.